# DHCPD configuration by interfaces

Tags: ubuntu, ip, dhcp, dhcp-server, ipv4

I have two interfaces on a machine running Ubuntu 14.04 LTS. Which has two different interfaces namely eth0 and eth1.

I need to give IP addresses to the clients by the interfaces.

For example,

Any client try to connect by eth0 and needs an IP address, I want to give in range 10.10.0.1 - 10.10.0.100

And the other clients connecting by eth1 should get an IP address in range 10.20.0.1 - 10.20.0.100

Is it possible by writing rules in dhcpd.conf?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you are using ISC DHCPd it is based on the subnet:

```
subnet 10.10.0.0 netmask 255.255.255.0 {
    range 10.10.0.1 10.10.0.100;
}

subnet 10.20.0.0 netmask 255.255.255.0 {
    range 10.20.0.1 10.20.0.100;
}
```

Your `eth0` interface should have an IPv4 address in the `10.10.0.0/24` subnet (I am assuming the subnets are a /24, you didn't mention) and the `eth1` interface should have an IPv4 address in the `10.20.0.0/24` subnet.

If you want to limit the interfaces that `dhcpd` looks at you can put those in `/etc/default/isc-dhcp-server`.

PS: `man dhcpd.conf` is your friend.